# SQL filter top 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ask you to help me in filtering a table where I have 3 columns (scanned tagID, date/time of scan, scaner mac address).

| tagID | tme | mac |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 000A000B000C000D000E000F | 04.07.2021T11:44:08Z | 63584030653439 |
| 000A000B000C000D000E000F | 04.07.2021T12.59.01Z | 73594035653865 |
| 000A000B000C000D000E000F | 04.07.2021T11:44:08Z | 63584030653439 |
| 120A000B000C000D000E000F | 04.07.2021T12.59.01Z | 73594035653865 |
| 130A000B000C000D000E000F | 04.07.2021T11:44:08Z | 63584030653439 |
| 140A000B000C000D000E000F | 04.07.2021T12.59.01Z | 73594035653865 |
| 150A000B000C000D000E000F | 04.07.2021T11:44:08Z | 63584030653439 |
| 550A000B000C000D000E000F | 04.07.2021T12.59.01Z | 73594035653865 |
| 0067895B000C000D000E000F | 04.07.2021T11:44:08Z | 63584030653439 |
| 0007695B000C000D000E000F | 04.07.2021T12.59.01Z | 73594035653865 |
| 00459ASB000C000D000E000F | 04.07.2021T11:44:08Z | 63584030653439 |
| 0235466B000C000D000E000F | 04.07.2021T12.59.01Z | 73594035653865 |

From this table, I need to be filtered last 1 row for each mac, where tagID = "000A000B000C000D000E000F" and tme(date) = today.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 2):

In Standard SQL, this would look something like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by mac order by tme desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where tagID = '000A000B000C000D000E000F' and
            tme >= current_date and
            tme < current_date + interval '1 day'
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Date/time functions vary by database, so you might need to tweak those for your database.

Note:  If you have only those three columns, then aggregation is sufficient:

```
select mac, tagID, max(tme)
from t
where tagID = '000A000B000C000D000E000F' and
      tme >= current_date and
      tme < current_date + interval '1 day'
group by mac, tagID
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I forgot  to tell you, the tme column is declared as nvchar(50) and not date/time, and the table name is scans. With the command you told me, the SQL server return an error.

Comment: @VasNorbert . . . Fix your data model!  In the mean time, convert the value to a proper date/time.